# VSCode does not automatically activate python interpreter of conda environment in WSL2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, wsl-2, virtual-environment

I have installed (Mini) Conda in an Ubuntu 20.04 instance running on WSL2, and I have created a virtual environment (`myenv`).

First, the path to the interpreter does not appear when I perform `Python: Select Interpreter`, so I have manually inserted it.

However, upon opening a new instance of the terminal, `source activate myenv` is not automatically run. I think VSCode is not aware that I am working with WSL2 (e.g. when opening the dialog box for selecting the interpreter, it searches only for windows executables).

Has someone encountered the problem and solved it?

Comment: Can you now see a WSL indicator in the bottom left corner? Have you looked at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) page?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, by clicking on the bottom left corner, selecting `New WSL Window using Distro...` and then selecting my WSL Ubuntu distro. VSCode was only opening the WSL terminal, but it was running locally on Windows.